# Building a kernel module on Centos 7 with a CMake file

Tags: cmake, linux-kernel, centos7

Sorry for the length.  I have tried to include as much information as possible.

A device I work with randomly fails to start at boot - this is a well known issue with the device and there are lots of posts on the web with no known solution except reboot.

So the task is to look in dmesg for a certain string that if present means the device has failed to start and the system needs rebooting.  A simple call to system() with boot seems to do the job.

A unit test that proves this would be nice. The idea is to look for a non-existant uuid in the dmesg log to prove that it fails to find one and then to write a different uuid to the log and then search for that.  Proving it works in both cases.

First thing was to hit up google:  Find you can write to the kernel log with `# echo '<4>Foo: Message' | sudo tee /dev/kmsg` which works from terminal but the `sudo` may cause issue in the unit test.

The next thing I looked at was accessing it via code. The unit tests are written in C++ and the library is googletest.

Most posts talk about writing a `Makefile` and `kbuild`.  I am working in a build system where we have `cmake` called from a shell script.

After several hours of searching and trying things, I decided to ask here.

I have installed

```sh
kernel.x86_64                                                      3.10.0-1062.el7                                                @anaconda
kernel.x86_64                                                      3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7                                           @updates 
kernel-devel.x86_64                                                3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7                                           @updates 
kernel-devel.x86_64                                                3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7                                           @updates 
kernel-headers.x86_64                                              3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7                                           @updates 
kernel-tools.x86_64                                                3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7                                           @updates 
kernel-tools-libs.x86_64                                           3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7
```

`uname -r` gives `3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64` which seems to suggest I have the kernel headers and devel files installed.

Doing a `find /. -name module.h` lists:

```sh
...
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/module.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64/include/asm-generic/module.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/module.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64/include/trace/events/module.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64/include/uapi/linux/module.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/module.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/asm-generic/module.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/module.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/trace/events/module.h
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/uapi/linux/module.h
...
```

It maybe that I am trying to link files in `/3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64/` when I should be linking to `3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/`.  Listing installed yum packages via `sudo yum list | grep linux-d` returns

```
libselinux-devel.x86_64                    2.5-15.el7             @base         
libhbalinux-devel.i686                     1.0.17-2.el7           base          
libhbalinux-devel.x86_64                   1.0.17-2.el7           base          
libselinux-devel.i686                      2.5-15.el7             base          
syslinux-devel.x86_64                      4.05-15.el7            base
```

My CMakeFiles.txt looks like

```
project( X_test )

set( TEST_SOURCE
    X_test.cpp
)

execute_process(COMMAND uname -r OUTPUT_VARIABLE uname_r OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

include_directories(/usr/src/kernels/${uname_r}/include)
link_directories(/lib/modules/${uname_r}/build)

add_library(source-lib STATIC source.c)
```

Anything else in there has been commented out to prevent confusion.

Without the lines `include_directories` or `link_directories` I get the error

```
 #include <linux/module.h>
```

With those lines in I get the error:

```
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/kernel.h:6:0,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/time.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/user/git/asdo/Services/DCO-3303/test/source.c:1:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/linkage.h:7:25: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/linkage.h>
```

The code I am compiling is the standard `printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");` which you can [see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/140354/how-to-add-message-that-will-be-read-with-dmesg).

How do I go about compiling code that uses a kernel call through CMake?

Comment: Using Linux kernel build system you automatically got all include directory, macro definitions, link flags, suitable for the Linux kernel. Also, Linux kernel uses its own tools for create `.ko` files. CMake is aware about none of these things. Adding them into `CMakeLists.txt` (or toolchain) is possible, but quite difficult. E.g. aside from adding `include/` into include directories list, you need to add `arch/x86/include` directory, which contains x86-specific headers. I wouldn't recommend using for building kernel modules anything except Linux Kernel build system.

Comment: Does [this blog post](https://musteresel.github.io/posts/2020/02/cmake-template-linux-kernel-module.html) help?